# How to connect to MongoDB replica set?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to connect to MongoDB cluster using

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

It shows me an error

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND messenger-mongodb-1
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  messenger-mongodb-1:
    container_name: messenger-mongodb-1
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    command: mongod --replSet messenger-mongodb-replica-set --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - messenger-mongodb-cluster
    volumes:
      - messenger-mongodb-1-data:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - messenger-mongodb-2
      - messenger-mongodb-3
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:\"messenger-mongodb-replica-set\",members:[{_id:0,host:\"messenger-mongodb-1\"},{_id:1,host:\"messenger-mongodb-2\"},{_id:2,host:\"messenger-mongodb-3\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  messenger-mongodb-2:
    container_name: messenger-mongodb-2
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    command: mongod --replSet messenger-mongodb-replica-set --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    networks:
      - messenger-mongodb-cluster
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=messenger-db
    volumes:
      - messenger-mongodb-2-data:/data/db

  messenger-mongodb-3:
    container_name: messenger-mongodb-3
    image: mongo:6.0.3
    command: mongod --replSet messenger-mongodb-replica-set --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    networks:
      - messenger-mongodb-cluster
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=messenger-db
    volumes:
      - messenger-mongodb-3-data:/data/db

networks:
  messenger-mongodb-cluster:

volumes:
  messenger-mongodb-1-data:
  messenger-mongodb-2-data:
  messenger-mongodb-3-data:
```

I run it like

```
docker-compose up -d
```

How can I connect to my replica set?

I want to use it for the local development of my node.js application

My operating system is Windows 11 Pro

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017` connects to a stand-alone MongoDB. For connection to replica set it would be like `mongodb://messenger-mongodb:27017,messenger-mongodb-1:27017,messenger-mongodb-2:27017/?replicaSet=messenger-mongodb-replica-set`

Comment: Instead of `rs.status().ok` I would suggest to check for `db.hello().isWritablePrimary` which returns `true` when `rs.init()` is really finished.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It shows me an error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND messenger-mongodb-1`. I tried it on Mac and Windows. The same error :(